how to match a range of value to other columns and return the column name if matched
Would really appreciate help for this that I've spent days on trying to work out...
I have 2 dataframes, df1 which have a range of years:
df1 <-data.frame(hospid =c("A", "B", "C"),
                 ga_yr =c("2009", "2004", "1999"),
                 wec_yr=c("2011", "2000", "2006"),
                 test_yr = c("2015", "2006", "2014"))
df1

and df2 that has a year whom I'd like to return the column name (ga_yr/wec_yr/test_yr) if the year is within range of +/- 2 years and matched to hospid
df2 <- data.frame(hospid =c("A", "B", "C"),
                     year=c("2010", "2002", "2016"))
df2

desired output:



hospid
year
from




A
2010
ga_yr


B
2002
wec_yr


C
2016
test_yr



Would be a huge bonus too if you could let me know how it would work if say it falls within the range of 2 columns, so say for A the year 2010 is actually within range for ga_yr and wec_yr.. how would you account for this?
Thank you so much!
I've tried fuzzyjoin and adding new columns with year1 (as +2 years to year) and year2 (as -2 years to year) but have not found a way to return the column name of the year that falls within the range.
